# .gitignore not matching subdirectories

Tags: git, gitignore

I have directory tree like this:

```
__pycache__
systems
    __pycache__
    ...
components
    __pycache__
    ...
...
```

I tried the following `.gitignore`s to ignore all `__pycache__` directories. However, they are not working - only the first one is ignored.

`**/__pycache__/` and `__pycache__/`

How do I ignore all of them?

Comment: `__pycache__/` should work if it's at top-level, but remember that if you've already `git add`ed the files you have to `git rm` them yourself.

Comment: I haven't added them yet. Because I am on Windows, do I have to use a backslash instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Because I am on Windows, do I have to use a backslash instead

No, you do not need to use a backslash.
This is enough to ignore *all* `_pycache__/` folders:

```
__pycache__/
```

Make sure your `.gitignore` is at the root folder of your repository.

Check that this has an empty output:
`git check-ignore -v -- components/_pycache__/aFile`

To be sure, try this and then check again:
`git rm --cached -r components/_pycache__/`